# What's the relationship of Sarah Jones with The Vampire Diaries?

Tags: the-vampire-diaries

In the end of the last episode of *The Vampire Diaries*, there was a text:

> In Loving Memory of
>   SARAH JONES
>
> 1986 – 2014

I googled only to find she was a crew of TVD team. What was her job position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been reported that Sarah Jones was [a camera assistant](http://hollywoodlife.com/2014/02/28/vampire-diaries-sarah-jones-tribute-crew-member-died-in-memory/).

This matches up with her activities when [she was struck by a train](http://www.ibtimes.com/vampire-diaries-crew-member-sarah-jones-dies-midnight-rider-train-accident-1557225) and the [Slates For Sarah](https://www.facebook.com/slatesforsarah) campaign that has emerged from the tragedy (camera assistants are often the ones who "clap" the slates when cameras begin rolling).

Answer (score 6):

She worked on the Vampire Diaries as a 2nd Unit Cinematographer (and slate operator) and recently died in a train accident when filming "[Midnight Rider](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2835050/)"

[image: Sarah Jones - Vampire Diaries]

According to the [Entertainmentwise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sejn.jpg) website;

> "An investigation into the death of Sarah Jones, an Atlanta-based
>   second assistant camera operator, is reportedly taking place following
>   her death on February 20 after a train struck her during production
>   for the Gregg Allman biopic Midnight Rider.
>
> Jones was at work on the first day of production for the big screen
>   biopic last week when the accident occured. TheWrap report that the
>   27-year-old was killed when a train smashed into a bed the crew had
>   placed on a trestle for a dream sequence they were shooting. Several
>   other crew members as well as some cast managed to escape unhurt,
>   while others were injured by flying debris and taken to hospital"

[image]

The Vampire Diaries crew have decided to take part in the #[SlatesForSarah](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/envelope/cotown/la-et-ct-sarah-jones-social-media-20140225,0,7571920.story) campaign which was set up on Twitter by Jones' family and friends after her death.